# Popup window value is not getting reflected in parent window

Tags: javascript, jsp

I tried to get value of pop up window in textbox of parent window. But it's not worked. Could any one helped on this?

Parent.jsp

```
<style>
 a:hover, a:active {
   background-color:red ;
 }
</style>

<form action="FirstTest" method="post" id="TestForm">
   <input type="text" id="PrintHere"/ ><br><br>
   <a   target="_blank" onclick="SelectName('POST')"> Repository Link </a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function SelectName(methodType) { 
    var win=window.open("Popup.jsp", "thePopUp", "width=300,height=100, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable");
    win.focus();           
}
</script>
```

Popup.jsp

```
<form id="PopUpForm">
    <input type="text" id="ddlNames"> <br /> <br />
    <input type="button" value="Select" onclick="SetName();" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function SetName() {
    if ((window.opener != null) && !(window.opener.closed)) {

    var Textvalue;
        Textvalue.value = document.getElementById("ddlNames").value;

        var TextBox = window.opener.document.getElementById("PrintHere");
        TextBox.value = Textvalue.value
    }
    window.close();
}     </script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Just give 5 minutes to add the code. Application giving error while adding the code.

Comment: Check the working example on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below on Popup.jsp

```
<form id="PopUpForm">
    <input type="text" id="ddlNames"> <br /> <br />
    <input type="button" value="Select" onclick="SetName();" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function SetName() {
    if ((window.opener != null) && !(window.opener.closed)) {

        var TextBox = window.opener.document.getElementById("PrintHere");
        TextBox.value = document.getElementById("ddlNames").value;
    }
    window.close();
}     
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks GUISSOUMA Issam